# How can my app programatically fetch all of it's console logs?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am looking for **a way to programatically pull all of my application logs** that are shown in console.

.

**I DO NOT WANT** to just be able to see them, so using xcode as a preview will not work for me.

What I want is my users to be able to send me those logs along with feedback any time since app is in beta phase and plain user explanations are not good enough for proper debugging at my end.

So, what **I DO WANT** is some iOS analogy for Android's logcat command which is being used somehow like this:

```
final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
final InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
```

... then you manipulate the stream into whatever you need to do with it, in my case, to create a String object that i would pass on to my log service.

[image: include debug logs]

**SO FAR in my investigation** I was only being able to find [this](https://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/accessing-the-ios-system-log/) option, but I would appreciate if something easier to integrate into Swift app is available.

Also, *os.log* module is used for logging, but I wasn't able to find an option where it allows loading the logs. Or my understanding of the following explanation found [HERE](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging) is not good enough:

*Use the Console app or the log command-line tool to view and filter log messages.*

---

**EDIT:**

**END USER SHOULD NOT INTERRACT WITH LOGS** in any way other than just clicking the submit button while switch for debug logs is ON.

So @matt NO - this is not the duplicate of the linked issue.
End users should NOT have to download something else too in order to be able to feed me with my own app logs.

That is a classic killer of user experience and should not even be approved as a solver on the linked post either.

Answer (score 0):

To your last point. That explanation is telling you to connect your phone to a mac and use the "Console" application (or command line tool) to extract the console logs e.g. https://support.apple.com/en-ie/guide/console/welcome/mac

The first link you have provided (using ASL) is the only solution I'm aware of to do this natively. 2 other options would be:

1. Use a server/cloud based analytical/event tracking system to log messages for each user. If someone sends an issue you can search the logs to see what happened. (Be careful about storing personal information though).
2. You could write your own class / function that takes in a string, and writes it to a text file and logs it to the console. During development you will see it in the console and in the wild it will store it. When you want the details, you could just read the text file and upload it. Need to be careful of it growing too big. And again depending on where its stored, personal data could be an issue.

I've always used option 1. There are many free services to do this and lots of solutions for releasing apps to test users provide this out of the box too. Microsofts AppCenter being one, and I believe is free unless you want CI/CD

Comment: Thanks for jumping in. As per alternatives 1st is not an option, but the 2nd one is something i was hoping some of the loggers that are out there would be able to do already. I'll gotta think it through a bit more I guess :D

Comment: @K15L33 id be surprised if there wasn't a cocoapod already doing this somewhere. I've never used one so I don't know any, option 1 is much easier to work with and I always opt for that.